# Assign static ip on docker 1.7

Tags: docker

Is there a way for setting a static IP on docker 1.7? I am currently running RedHat 6 so can only use Docker version up to 1.7.

The problem I am having is that default IP Docker defaults to an IP and its clashing with the one my server uses. Is there a way to specifically tell Docker to use a certain IP 127.0.0.2 for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker-compose to start up your containers. In that file you can define `ipv4_address` which will assign an static IP to your container. Here is an example

```
version: "2"
services:
  SERVICE1:
    image: $IMAGE_NAME
    container_name: $CONTAINER_NAME
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    networks:
        mynet:
          ipv4_address: 172.25.0.100 
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24
```